# How can check with C# if Microsoft Outlook is already open?

Tags: c#, outlook, email

I have tried looking for the answer to this question... Forgive me if I have overlooked it.

What I am trying to do is automate sending an email.  I have everything I want in this code but the code assumes that Outlook is NOT open.

Is there a way for me to test if Outlook is open before it opens another instance of Outlook?

```
                Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key =
           Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\microsoft\\windows\\currentversion\\app paths\\OUTLOOK.EXE");
            string path = (string)key.GetValue("Path");
            if (path != null)
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("OUTLOOK.EXE");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("There is no Outlook in this computer!", "SystemError", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

Comment: "the code assumes that Outlook is NOT open" <-- what does that mean?

Comment: You could use WMI -> select * from win32_process and check the name property there, if you can't find outlook.exe you can open it. another way could be [Process.GetProcessesByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry for not being as clear as possible.  What I am trying to say is that this code opens an instance of Outlook even if it is already open.  What I am trying to do is test to see if Outlook is open before opening another instance.

Comment: @Piggie_Pie Check the answer I posted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int procCount = 0;
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK");
foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
{
    procCount++;            
}
 if (procCount > 0)
{
  //outlook is open
}
```

Comment: No need for counter, you could just do processlist.length > 0

Comment: I used a modified version of this to get the result that i needed... THANK YOU!!!  I don't have enough rep to give you +Rep... sad day :(

Comment: @Piggie_Pie glad that I could help you :)

Comment: @Piggie_Pie -- if Irusu's answer satisfies your problem, please accept mark it as accepted, and that will be even better than a +1.

Comment: @Hambone - Thanks... I'm still new around here and didn't realize i could select the check mark :)  
Problem solved!

Answer (score 15):

Since I like clean one-liners, here's what I used:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Any())
  return true;
```

Comment: Clean solution nice. If you edit the the uppercase letter from "If" to lowercase - a copy/paste also works :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way you can test if Outlook is open, and if it is, you "grab" the current instance.  In your catch block, you can open your new instance the way you have listed:

```
Outlook.Application ol;

try
{
    ol = (Outlook.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // open your new instance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Process class e.g.

```
Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("outlook"); 
// empty array if no outlook process found.
if(localByName.Length > 0)
{ /*do work because outlook is already open*/}
else
{/* start outlook */}
```

another way could be a [wql-query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186146(VS.80).aspx)

```
WqlObjectQuery wqlQuery = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wqlQuery);

foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get()) 
{
    var name = process.GetPropertyValue("Name"); // e.g. outlook.exe
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Diagnostics; //to make the Process work

Process[ ] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName 
("OUTLOOK:);
If (processlist.Length>0)
{
//outlook is open
}
```